# Verb tense for an event that will happen, and happens every year

Tags: tiempos-verbales

I'm not sure which tense to use for this.

The event happens in August. But it happens *every* August, not just in the coming August.

> [En Agosto] hay **baile** en los calles y **escenifican** la batalla

*([In August] they dance in the streets and re-enact the battle)*

**escenificar**  is *to stage*

**bailar**  is *to dance*

Are the translations above correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `se` (passive) to express this

> En Agosto se baila en las calles y se escenifica la batalla
>
> In August they dance in the streets and re-enact the battle.

it can also be translated to this

> In August you dance in the streets and re-enact the battle

or even

> In August you dance in the streets and the battle is re-enacted.